# Batch commands only work when implemented on command line

Tags: batch-file, command-line, lidar

I have a script that performs the following workflow using FUSION (LiDAR processing) commands:

1. Clip LiDAR LAS files to polygon boundaries creating a unique LAS
   file for each polygon
2. Run `cloudmetrics` to record point cloud information on a per
   clipped LAS file basis

This is the script I created to accomplish steps 1 and 2:

```
set shapefile=D:\path\to\shapefile.shp
set inlas=D:\path\to\input\folder\containing\las\files
set clippedlas=D:\path\to\clipped\las\files
set outcsv=D:\output\csvfile.csv

dir %inlas%\*.las /b /s > %inlas%\MyLASList.txt

PolyClipData /multifile /shape:1,* %shapefile% %clippedlas%\clipped %inlas%\MyLASList.txt

dir %clippedlas%\*.las /b /s > %clippedlas%\MyLASList2.txt
cloudmetrics %clippedlas%\MyLASList2.txt %outcsv%
```

If I run this script as a `.bat` file by double-clicking the file, it creates some sort of endless loop at the `polyclipdata` command.  However, If I implement the script line-by-line on the command line, the workflow performs the required tasks.  Where am going wrong here?

Comment: If you run the commands line-by-line, do you use an elevated command prompt?

Comment: What is the name of your batch file?

Comment: @Wimmel Yes, I am essentially copying a line of text, pasting it to the command prompt and pressing return.

Comment: @Noodles `borealisbatch.bat`.

Comment: You could have problems with spaces in paths or filenames. Some description of the actual fault would help. Also, if `PolyClipData` is a batch file then you will need to use `call PolyClipData` and the problem could be that inside `PolyClipData.bat` it launches an executable called `PolyClipData`.

Comment: @Borealis but did you try to run the batch file elevated too?

Comment: To Noodles point - make sure your .BAT file is not named PolyClipData.bat or cloudmetrics.bat

Answer (score 1):

In a command prompt make this batch frile.

PathFind.bat

```
@echo off
echo. 
echo PathFind - Finds the first file in in a path
echo ======== = ===== === ===== ==== == == = ====
echo. 
echo Searching for %1 in %path%
echo. 
set a=%~$PATH:1
If "%a%"=="" (Echo %1 not found) else (echo %1 found at %a%)
```

Then TYPE the following lines which looks in the path for executable files.

```
pathfind PolyClipData.com
pathfind PolyClipData.bat
pathfind PolyClipData.cmd
pathfind PolyClipData.exe
pathfind PolyClipData.vbs
pathfind PolyClipData.js
pathfind PolyClipData.wsh
pathfind PolyClipData.wsf
pathfind PolyClipData.vbe
pathfind PolyClipData.jse
pathfind PolyClipData.lnk
pathfind PolyClipData.url
pathfind PolyClipData.pif
pathfind PolyClipData.msc
```

and a long shot

```
pathfind PolyClipData
```

If that finds nothing then you must be editing the batch file while it is running.

Answer (score 1):

When you run that file, are you in the Fusion folder on in another?? maybe you need to put the correct path to FUSION on the batch file, because Fusion command line executables need to be run from the fusion folder.

Try to put the right path: ..\PolyClipData (or the pathfind that Noodles points)